# Babel-CLI -- Using a package.json file to "watch" a directory does not update the compiled source

Tags: compilation, babeljs, watch, babel-cli

The goal here is to watch a directory and output the new files.

When saved *it should* ....

1. take every file in the directory and minify it
2. transpile every file that needs transpiling
3. add the minified file and the map in the same directory

What's actually happening ....

1. message displays that files were compiled
2. the .min "new" version of the file is not updated or changed and stays the same

### Here's the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "theme",
  "version": "1.0.448",
  "description": "Someones Theme",
  "main": "index.php",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch:babel-blocks": "npx babel blocks/jsxblock/*.jsx --watch --out-dir blocks/jsxblock/ --out-file-extension .min.js --source-maps"
  },
  "author": "Someone",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later"
}
```

### Here's the .babel.config.json file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "minify"
  ]
}
```

## UPDATE - 12/2/2020

Here's a link to a repl.it demo

https://repl.it/join/xldfgzre-juandahveed

If you've never used repl.it before, make sure you hit *control + shift + s* so that the terminal will come up.

Then you can run *npm run watch:babel-blocks* and see what happens.

In this instance, if you update the `blocks/jsxblock/editor.jsx` file, the watch flag will actually work, and the `blocks/jsxblock/editor.min.js` file will update with any changes you make.

The only thing I can think of, is that in my local instance ( which is really just a hyped up WordPress site with a build script ) I am using both the `devDependencies` and `dependencies` areas of my `package.json` file, whereas with repl.it I can only have things be in the `dependencies`. I did test this in my local environment and it did not fix anything.

Thoughts? Suggestions? Does anyone actually *know* the reason why?